# Can't add or delete resource elements in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, string

When I remove a string or any other resource element the list still shows that element.....and if I click on add then the window to add name and value doesn't show up.

this is the link to pic since i'm new so i can't post image files until i reach 10 rep points.... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B283560gG_9cem1nUlE4NzYybUE/edit?usp=sharing

So in that pic 1st image as soon as i click on add the window editing name and value vanishes.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. To receive more responses to your questions, you may want to clarify a bit more. Good luck!

Comment: I added a image link....can you help me out now

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an Eclipse user myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had this issue too. On my Mac, I can't add string resources through the resource editor. On my PC, it's not an issue. I wonder if it's a bundle issue when they upgraded.

What I've done is a hackaround. You can add the string resources through the graphical layout, right click and press Edit Text. Then you can press add String. Put in the value of the text that you want to display and give it a string id. Press okay and then it'll show up in both strings.xml and also your layout.

Hope this helps.